# Can't read values from JSON Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, key-value

I'm currently coding a script which will get the latest posts from my webpage to display them on my webpage. I already created a php script which will create a json array for my script to read from. The script actually reads the json just fine 
(This is the JSON we're talking about:

```
[
{
    "id":18,
    "title":"Linktest",
    "content":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/\">Dies ist ein Link<\/a>",
    "datetime":"2014-04-12T17:20:30.000Z"
    },
{
    "id":4,
    "title":"Noch ein Test",
    "content":"Dies ist noch ein Test!",
    "datetime":"2014-04-11T14:11:35.000Z"
    },
{
    "id":1,
    "title":"Test",
    "content":"Aloha Leute,\r\n<p>Das ist ein Testpost!<\/p>",
    "datetime":"2014-04-11T11:09:43.000Z"
    }
 ]
```

Now, for some odd reason I cannot read values from this JSON array by just doing for example: `response[1]`  ("response" being the variable I've assigned the array to) because that's just giving me a white space when I'm trying to output it. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Edit: Here's the javascript code:

```
//the replace is to display the data without html tags, it was just for testing purposes
var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
    });
    var lol = document.getElementById("lol");
    lol.innerHTML = response;
```

Comment: Provide a piece of code please

Comment: What makes you think that `response` contains that JSON?  How are you trying to print it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the received string to actual JSON object before trying to access it:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
//now you can access it like this: jsonObject[0].title
```

Comment: I've realised that I actually made a mistake in the php file itself. It's working now :D